# What query do I use to return unique rows in <Model>.find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am making a node.js application -- Ornament manager using MongoDB and mongoose.

I have a collection that has the following schema:-

```
var DetailsSchema = new Schema({
owner: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'owner', required:true},
ornament: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Ornament', required:true},
location:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Location', required:true},
date: {type:Date, required:true, default: Date.now()}
```

Every time an owner removes an ornament from a particular location, the record will be inserted into the collection rather than updated for the history functionality to work.
I would like to return all the ornaments present in a given location.

```
Details.find({location: req.params.id},'ornament')
.populate('ornament')
.exec((err,results)=>{
    if(err){return next(err);}
    res.render('location_detail',{results:results})
})
```

This returns all the ornaments that are present and also that were present at some point of time. To eliminate redundancy and incorrect data, I want to return only those fields that has the latest date(for documents that have the same ownerID and ornamentID) and present in the locationID: req.params.id

Any workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added an inactive date field that would automatically change to Date.now() when a transaction took place. Question solved